# How to get the R^2 of a tobit regression

Tags: stata

I am using the global lists method to do a simple Tobit regression in Stata. However, I can only get the Pseudo R2 and I would like to know how to get the R2. I have seen this in other papers, where authors include the R2 as well as the pseudo R2 in their results table.

This is the command I used in Stata to do the Tobit regression:

```
tobit $ylist $xlist, ll(0)
```

And this is what I get as results of the regression:

```
    Tobit regression                                  Number of obs   =   720
                                                  LR chi2(11)     =     634.77
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0000
Log likelihood = -1069.1367                       Pseudo R2       =     0.2289

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     lnFDI |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     lnEPUex |   .2463733   .1107293     2.23   0.026     .0289769    .4637698
     lngex   |   2.105098   .2226805     9.45   0.000     1.667906     2.54229
     lngim   |   .2139065   .0572308     3.74   0.000     .1015444    .3262685
    rlnPIex  |   .3114163   .0572274     5.44   0.000     .1990609    .4237717
    rlnPIim  |   .1422837   .0532301     2.67   0.008     .0377763    .2467912
    rln_GDP  |  -.0225078   .0067543    -3.33   0.001    -.0357686    -.009247
    rln_pu   |  -.0731599   .0080628    -9.07   0.000    -.0889897     -.05733
    lnreedim |   4.846298   .4855235     9.98   0.000     3.893062    5.799534
        lndi |  -.2364755   .0507064    -4.66   0.000    -.3360282   -.1369228
     bording |   .0116308   .2489393     0.05   0.963    -.4771156    .5003771
     opening |  -.4729668   .1726833    -2.74   0.006    -.8119987    -.133935
       _cons |  -33.79161   2.927544   -11.54   0.000     -39.5393   -28.04392
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      /sigma |   1.068198   .0281495                      1.012932    1.123465
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Obs. summary:          0  left-censored observations
                       720     uncensored observations
                         0 right-censored observations
```

Comment: How do you define "the" R-sq here? You could predict the predictions and then get the correlation between those and the observed responses. I am not clear that is especially useful, but it's one definition.

Comment: A very similar question is also posed on Statalist at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1373827-how-to-obtain-r-2-for-tobit-and-partial-r-2-for-gmm

Comment: I would like to get the R-sq that shows the percent of variance explained by the model, could I use the pseudo- R-sq to do this?

Comment: No. It is defined in terms of likelihoods. This is documented: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/pseudo-r2/index.html As in my previous comment, squaring the correlation is closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you have several options here.

**Option 1: Compute it yourself** 
The R-square statistic is defined as the sum of square differences between the observed values and the predicted values, divided by the sum of square differences between the observed values and the sample average values.   If your observed outcome variable is ***Y***, your predicted value is ***F***, and your average ***Yav*** is computed across observed values of ***Y*** ,  then R-square is defined as : ∑(***Yi***-***Fi***)^2 /∑(***Yi***-***Yav***)^2.

One way to interpret this ratio is that it measures how well your predictor ***F*** does compare to using the sample mean ***Yav*** as a predictor.

This can be implemented in Stata with the following (pseudo code, need real variable name for Y, and need some care with variables to get correct sums):

```
    (code here to run your Tobit first)
    predict, F
    quietly sum Y
    gen Yav=r(mean)
    gen sq_res=(Y-F)^2
    gen sq_tot=(Y-Yav)^2
    egen SSres= sum(sq_res)
    egen SStot=sum(sq_tot)
    gen R-square=SSres/SStot
```

There are better ways of computing this measure such as using Stata matrix language, or predefined return scalars, but this procedure explains to you what you are doing.

**Option 2: Use another, better Loss Function** 
The R-square statistic is only *one* measure of goodness-of-fit, there are others.  Generally speaking, it is a special form of a **Loss Function**, defined as some ***L(Y,F,Z)*** that measures how much your predicted regression values deviate from the observed values, where ***Y*** is the observed outcome variable , ***F*** is your predicted value, and ***Z*** some other variables that may cause your model to be less accurate.   For example, the simplest Loss Function you can define is ***L(Y,F,Z)***=***Y-F***.   Thus the R-square is defined as R-square=***L(Y,F,Yav)*** as shown above.  You can see then that R-square as defined is not a sample-independent measure, since it changes depending on ***Yav***.   As a measure of the accuracy of your tool, if it changes from sample to sample, it is probably not a good one.  If you choose to interpret the R-square measure as percentage of variation explained/unexplained by XYZ, then you have to live with the sample-dependent nature, but if you are interested in how accurate your Tobit is, I would suggest others, and some other function ***L(Y,F)*** will have that sample-independent property.  I would note here that while everyone uses squared deviations as a habit, they tend to be sensitive to outliers.  Absolute deviations would not be, so you may consider that.

**Option 3: Use Previous Literature** 
Coming up with your own Loss Function, while satisfying, may get you into issues if your measure is not well behaved.  You can use Loss Functions that others have devised.  For example Elliott and Timmermann (2016) gives a comprehensive treatment, and many many examples of well-behaved functions, including mean absolute error loss function, piece-wise linear loss functions, and loss functions for binary outcomes such as the Kuipers score.   Artis and Marcellino (2001) , Capistrán and Timmermann (2009), Varian (1975),and Zellner (1986a) all used Linex (linear exponential) loss functions, with the latter employing a more intuitively clear Bayesian approach.

**References**

*Elliott, G., and A. Timmermann. 2004. Optimal forecast combinations under general loss functions and forecast error distributions. Journal of Econometrics 122:47–79.*

*Graham Elliott, Allan Timmermann-Economic Forecasting-Princeton University Press (2016), Chapter 2, pp.13-37*

*Artis, M., and M. Marcellino. 2001. Fiscal forecasting: The track record of the IMF, OECD and EC. Econometrics Journal 4:20–36.*

*Capistrán, C., and A. Timmermann. 2009. Forecast combination with entry and exit of experts. Journal of Business & Economic Statistics 27:428–40.*

*Varian, H. R. 1975. A Bayesian approach to real estate assessment. Studies in Bayesian econometrics and statistics in honor of Leonard J. Savage 195–208.*

*Zellner, A. 1986a. Bayesian estimation and prediction using asymmetric loss functions. Journal of the American Statistical Association 81:446–51.*

Comment: Using `predict` and then `correlate` and squaring the result according to taste is another way.

Comment: The pseudocode here is a little rough if taken too literally. For example, `sum()` produces cumulative sums and so it is essential to take the value in the last observation.

Comment: I understand the cumulative sum which is why I wrote`egen`, and not `gen` , but will edit answer to emphasize this.

Comment: Yes on `predict` and then `correlate`, which will work.  However, trying to approach problem for this user using the more intuitively obvious Loss Function was the intent.  The `correlate` route preserves the unexplained variance interpretation of the R-square statistic, and if that had made  made sense there would have been no need for this question, and of course no need for the long-winded, triple option Loss Function route.

Comment: You are correct on `egen` but note also that `egen`'s`sum()` is undocumented in favour of `total()` as from Stata 9 onwards. It still works. Using `summarize, meanonly` and then its `r(sum)` is a better way to pick up a single scalar containing a sum.